# How to get the real pathname with locale in next.js middlewares

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, internationalization, middleware

For SEO reasons, I'm attempting to redirect (using 301) all routes from `/es/[*REST OF-ROUTE*]` to `/[*REST OF-ROUTE*]`; however, as you can see in the screenshot below, the locale in the path is removed in the request.

[image: Logs, CURL request's, next.config.js, pages/_middlewire.ts]

*pages/_middlewire.ts*

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server';

const middleware = (req: NextRequest) => {
  console.log('NextUrl Pathname: ', req.nextUrl.pathname);
  console.log('Request URL: ', req.url);
  return NextResponse.next();
};

export default middleware;
```

*next.config.js*

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  localeDetection: true,
  i18n: {
    locales: ['es', 'en'],
    defaultLocale: 'es',
  },
  ...
};
```

So, is there any way to obtain the real pathname in the middleware function?

**Node's version:** 16
**NextJs's Version:** 12.1
**React's version:** 17.0.2

If you need more information, let me know.

Best regards!.

Comment: You should be able to access the locale using `req.nextUrl.locale`. See https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/server#nextrequest. I'd also recommend updating to Next.js 12.2 where Middleware has become stable - see [Middleware Upgrade Guide](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/middleware-upgrade-guide).

Comment: @juliomalves `req.nextUrl` has the locale regardless of whether or not it has the locale in the patname (for example: `url.dom/es/` or `url.dom/` both have **es** in locale). Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here are steps to hide the default locale from the URL in next.js (you need to upgrade to next.js 13.1+):

1. Add `skipMiddlewareUrlNormalize: true,` to `next.config.js`. More info: [Next.js docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/middleware#advanced-middleware-flags);
2. Make redirect in next middleware:

```js
import { NextResponse, userAgent } from 'next/server';

export async function middleware(req) {
  const { isBot } = userAgent(req);
  const redirectStatus = isBot ? 301 : 302;
  const { defaultLocale } = req.nextUrl;

  if (req.url.endsWith(`/${defaultLocale}`) || req.url.includes(`/${defaultLocale}/`)) {
    const urlStringWithoutDefaultLocale = req.url.endsWith(`/${defaultLocale}`)
      ? req.url.replace(`/${defaultLocale}`, '')
      : req.url.replace(`/${defaultLocale}/`, '/');
    const urlWithoutDefaultLocale = new URL(urlStringWithoutDefaultLocale);

    return NextResponse.redirect(urlWithoutDefaultLocale, { status: redirectStatus });
  }
  return NextResponse.next();
}
```